# Unity Lerping between multiple matierals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a need to lerp through 10 different materials attached to one of my game objects but for some reason, the code I have written doesn't work. I have spent the past hour trying to workout why and I'm pretty burnt out.

Could someone with fresher eyes please take a look and see if I'm doing some stupid?

```
public class LerpMaterials : MonoBehaviour
{

public List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();

public float lerpSpeed;

int currentMaterialNo;
Material currentMaterial;
Material targetMaterial;
bool lerpingMaterial;

float lerp;


void Start ()
{
    if (materials.Count < 2)    return;

    currentMaterialNo = 0;
    currentMaterial = materials[currentMaterialNo];
    targetMaterial = materials[currentMaterialNo+1]; 
}



void Update ()
{
    if (materials.Count < 2)    return;

    lerp += lerpSpeed;

    renderer.material.Lerp(currentMaterial, targetMaterial, lerp);

    if (lerp >= 1)
        SwitchMaterial();

}


void SwitchMaterial()
{
    if ( currentMaterialNo >= (materials.Count - 1) )
        currentMaterialNo = 0;
    else
        currentMaterialNo++;

    currentMaterial = materials[currentMaterialNo];
    targetMaterial = materials[currentMaterialNo++];

    lerp = 0;
}
```

}

My list holds every single material and my mesh renderer also holds the required materials as well. But nothing happens other than an instance of the first material appearing in the material renderer. No other movement.

Comment: what is your lerpspeed set to?

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy thanks for dropping in over a year after the OP has accepted the answer below from dewB that used the exact answer I was leading to. 

You mistakenly believe the OP was asking how to lerp textures. Maybe you found this thread looking how to lerp textures, but that wasn't what he asked. I have no reason to believe he wasn't attempting to use the material lerp as intended. And again, since the lerp speed answer was accepted, one can assume OP was able to get everything working as intended after that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set your lerpSpeed.

If lerpSpeed = 0, then no change will happen.

If lerpSpeed > 1, then once per frame, it will change the material.

Since the first material is the only thing showing up and not looping through every material rapidly, lerpSpeed is probably 0.  However, you will end up with a problem with this function in that it will change every frame or extremely rapidly.  The issue being with how lerp is being incremented.

Instead of:

```
lerp += lerpSpeed;
```

Use this instead:

```
lerp += lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

What this will do is instead of incrementing lerp by lerpSpeed once per frame (which is dependent on the computer's performance), instead, it will increment lerpSpeed by lerpSpeed every second, which will ensure a consistent effect across every machine.